# Come si esprime il fatto che alcuni studenti non sono presenti a scuola?

Tags: phrase-request

In Catalogna, la scuola è cominciata per i bambini e i ragazzi il passato 14 settembre. Non sono ancora passate due settimane ma, nel posto dove lavoro, parecchi studenti non possono essere presenti a causa della pandemia e ogni giorno che passa ce ne sono di più. Probabilmente, da domani o da lunedì, un'intera classe dovrà passare a casa alcuni giorni di quarantena, ma non lo posso ancora assicurare perché tutto si sta svolgendo in una grandissima confusione.

Nella mia lingua, per esprimere il fatto che uno studente non è presente a scuola, nei documenti ufficiali si usa il termine "absència" (in catalano, immagino che in castigliano si usi "ausencia", ma non ne sono del tutto sicura perché nella mia comunità autonoma tutti i documenti dell'ambito scolastico sono in catalano).

Nel linguaggio comune, però, questo si esprime con il verbo "faltar". Potrei dire, per esempio, "a l'institut on treballo falten molts estudiants a causa de la pandèmia" (un "institut" è una scuola pubblica di insegnamento secondario) o "a l'institut on treballo falten molts alumnes a causa de la pandèmia".

Come posso rendere questa stessa idea in italiano?

- Nella scuola dove lavoro molti studenti sono assenti a causa della pandemia?
- Nella scuola dove lavoro molti studenti non sono presenti a causa della pandemia?
- Altri?

Comment: Si può anche dire “mancano”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anche in italiano si usa il termine "assenza" ma contrariamente (a quanto ho capito) al catalano non è percepito come particolarmente formale.
La frase più naturale è la prima:

- Nella scuola dove lavoro molti studenti sono assenti a causa della pandemia

Comment: Se si può anche dire "mancano molti studenti", come proposto da @egreg, potresti aggiungerlo alla risposta in modo che sia più completa?

Comment: @Charo - essere assenti è l’espressione più usata e corretta. Infatti a scuola si fa l’appello dei presenti e degli assenti.

Answer (score 2):

La parola *assenza* è in effetti dotta e la si trova comunemente in testi giuridici e burocratici, meno in altri testi. Tuttavia *assenza* e *assente* hanno un uso comunissimo in ambito scolastico: se uno studente non è a scuola è *assente* e sul registro di classe viene annotata la sua *assenza*.

Lo si impara fin da piccoli: un tempo l'insegnante faceva tutti i giorni l'appello. Motivo? Mia nonna, quando cominciò la sua attività di maestra elementare, aveva una classe di oltre cento bambini che divideva in due turni, mattina e pomeriggio. Ovviamente era quasi impossibile riconoscere a vista chi c'era e chi mancava. Perciò si chiamavano i bambini a uno a uno; chi c'era rispondeva ‘presente’, se qualcuno non rispondeva, qualcun altro diceva ‘assente’.

Naturalmente, con classi meno numerose, la pratica non è necessaria, ma era comunque uso fare l'appello i primi giorni in modo da imparare i nomi. In seguito, segnare le assenze diventa una questione di contare i presenti, dedurre il numero degli assenti e identificarli.

Quindi ognuno associa “assenza” principalmente all'ambito scolastico, magari non conoscendo le altre accezioni del termine. Usare “non presente” sarebbe una forzatura, quindi

> Nella scuola dove lavoro molti studenti sono assenti a causa della pandemia

è perfettamente comprensibile e anzi è la forma di scelta. Si potrebbe anche dire

> Nella scuola dove lavoro mancano molti studenti a causa della pandemia

e il significato sarebbe lo stesso, sebbene *mancare* abbia anche altre accezioni. La precisazione *a causa della pandemia* dice che la mancanza è temporanea, non strutturale come in

> Nella scuola dove lavoro mancano molti studenti per poter istituire una nuova sezione

in cui la mancanza non è temporanea. Qui, ovviamente, *assenza* sarebbe fuori posto.

Nel gergo militare non si usa rispondere *assente*. All'appello del plotone durante l'adunata mattutina, chi c'è risponde *presente*; se uno non risponde, il caporale di giornata può dire *marca visita* per indicare che il soldato pensa di essere malato. Altrimenti sono guai, perché il soldato che *manca all'appello* potrebbe incorrere nel reato di diserzione (propria o impropria). Compito del furiere è di annotare sul foglio per l'appello i nomi dei soldati assenti per motivi giustificati (ricovero in infermeria, missione o licenza).